# Does inheritance of a large class take more memory than just calling the specific function within the class?

Tags: python, function, class, inheritance, methods

Does inheritance of a large class take more memory than just calling the specific function within the class?

For example, take Class A below. Which method is fastest and takes the least memory? Are they just the same and it's just a matter of syntax or does it actually make a difference?

```
class A(object):
    def function1(self):
        code
    def function2(self):
        code
    def function3(self):
        code
    def function4(self):
        code
    def function5(self):
        code
```

Method 1:

```
 class B(A):
    def function6(self):
         self.function1(argument)
```

Method 2:

```
 class B(object):
    def function6(self):
         A().function1(argument)
```

Method 3:

```
 class B(object):
    def function6(self):
         A.function1(self,argument)
```

In terms of preference and style, I want to go with Method 1, but I'm afraid that if Class A is really large and has a lot of functions that are not pertinent to class B that it will take more memory than necessary and slow things down. Is this the case or can I go with Method 1?

Comment: If you don't need an `A` instance's attributes, why is the function an instance method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the options take significantly more memory than the others. However, they also don't make sense in the same contexts.

- If you can call `A().function1(argument)` and have that do something reasonable, `function1` doesn't need to be a method of a class at all.
- `A.function1(self, argument)` doesn't make any sense if `self` isn't an instance of `A`. If it *is* an instance of `A`, it's better to use `self.function1(argument)`. Particularly in Python 2, `A.function1(self, argument)` will raise a `TypeError` if `self` isn't an instance of `A`.
- `self.function1(argument)` is the most reasonable, but if you're inheriting from `A` just to get access to its instance methods, you might want to rethink the way your program's classes and methods are organized.

Answer (score 3):

This wont change anything, as methods are created (more or less) statically (unless you create classes dynamically).

Instance attributes could be more important, but from question I guess that this is not the case.

Only memory optimization (that is relevant to classes and objects) would be to use [**slots**](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), but remember that: "premature optimisation is the root of all evil", so don't use them, **unless** you run into memory perfoemance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Method 3 seems wrong, since `self` is not an instance of `A`. This severely restricts what you can do with `self` in `function1`, and it doesn't work at all in Python 2.

Method 2 has a small overhead, since you construct an object.

There is no memory use or performance overhead associated with the number of functions in a class's base class(es). The memory used by an object does not vary according to the number of methods in its class or its bases, since they are not referenced in the object itself. So Method 1 would seem to be the best, provided the usual criteria for using inheritance apply to `A` and `B`. If `A` has many functions that are not pertinent to `B`, that might indicate that the usual criteria do *not* apply. Illogical inheritance usually *isn't* a good performance optimization. There may be some sensible way to call `function1` without creating an object, such as making it a classmethod.

Answer (score 0):

A is not a "large class" in the sense each instance has absolutely no instance attributes. Accordingly, to inherit from A will add exactly zero bloat to a subclass instance.

More fundamentally, your question represents an example of premature optimization. If you really have a performance problem, you should profile your code to see where the memory and time are being consumed. If you don't, write the code in the simplest possible way.